# Magento 1.9 admin menu is going to 404!

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml, custom, admin-controller

I am using custom module to getting tax report. It is working fine on demo site.

Below is the etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DS_News>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </DS_News>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <dsnews>
                    <file>ds_news.xml</file>
                </dsnews>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <routers>
            <dsnews><!-- Название узла dsnews, расположенного в секции config/frontend/routers/, может быть любым; единственное требование — это уникальность названия среди других роутеров системы-->
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>DS_News</module>
                    <frontName>news</frontName>
                </args>
            </dsnews>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <dsnews>
                <class>DS_News_Block</class>
            </dsnews>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <dsnews>
                <class>DS_News_Helper</class>
            </dsnews>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <dsnews>
                <class>DS_News_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>dsnews_resource</resourceModel>
            </dsnews>
            <dsnews_resource>
                <class>DS_News_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <table_news>
                        <table>ds_news_entities</table>
                    </table_news>
                </entities>
            </dsnews_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <dsnews_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>DS_News</module>
                </setup>
            </dsnews_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <dsnews module="dsnews">
                <title>Tax Report</title>
                <sort_order>123</sort_order>
                <action>dsnews_admin/adminhtml_news</action>
            </dsnews>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <dsnews_admin>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>DS_News</module>
                    <frontName>dsnews_admin</frontName>
                </args>
            </dsnews_admin>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

I have tried to do die in controller but it is not working. And other side the same code is working fine on demo site.

Controller code: DS/News/controllers/Adminhtml/NewsController.php

```
<?php

class DS_News_Adminhtml_NewsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        die('testing DS news extension');
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model = Mage::getModel('dsnews/news');
        if ($data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData()) {
            $model->setData($data)->setId($id);
        } else {
            $model->load($id);
        }
        Mage::register('current_news', $model);

        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('dsnews');
        $this->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('dsnews/adminhtml_news_edit_tabs'));
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('dsnews/adminhtml_news_edit'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model = Mage::getModel('dsnews/news');

        if ($data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData()) {
            $model->setData($data)->setId($id);
        } else {
            $model->load($id);
        }
        Mage::register('current_news', $model);

        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('dsnews');
        $this->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('dsnews/adminhtml_news_edit_tabs'));
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('dsnews/adminhtml_news_edit'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            try {
                $model = Mage::getModel('dsnews/news');
                $model->setData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
                if (!$model->getCreated()) {
                    $model->setCreated(now());
                }
                $model->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('News was saved successfully'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
                    'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')
                ));
            }
            return;
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Unable to find item to save'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
            try {
                Mage::getModel('dsnews/news')->setId($id)->delete();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('News was deleted successfully'));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $id));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function massDeleteAction()
    {
        $news = $this->getRequest()->getParam('news', null);

        if (is_array($news) && sizeof($news) > 0) {
            try {
                foreach ($news as $id) {
                    Mage::getModel('dsnews/news')->setId($id)->delete();
                }
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Total of %d news have been deleted', sizeof($news)));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please select news'));
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('wreport/daily')
            ->_addBreadcrumb('wreport Manager','wreport Manager');
        return $this;
    }

    public function exportAction()
    {

        $date = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ($date['created'] && $date['created1']) {
            $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date['created']));
            $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date['created1']));

            $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate));
            $dataOrders = $orders->getData();

            $arrayOrders = array();
            foreach ($dataOrders as $order) {

                 /*var_dump($order)/*['customer_firstname'] . ' ' . $order['customer_lastname'].'<br>';
                echo $order['created_at'].' '.$order['updated_at'].'<br>';
                echo '---------------------<br>';*/

                $ordermeth = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order['entity_id']);
                if (is_object($ordermeth->getShippingAddress())) {
                    $regionOrders = $ordermeth->getShippingAddress()->getRegion();
                    $curierName = $ordermeth->getShippingMethod();
                }

                $items = $ordermeth->getAllItems();
                $taxName = array();
                $qty = array();

                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order['increment_id']);
                    //var_dump($order);exit();
                    foreach ($order->getTracksCollection() as $_track){
                        $trackingNumber =  $_track->getNumber();
                        $titleTracking = $_track->getTitle();

                    }


                    $qtyProductInOrder = number_format($order['qty_ordered'], 0, '.', '');
                    $qtyOrder = number_format($item->getQtyOrdered(), 0, '.', '');
                    // foreach(
                    for ($i=1;$i <= $qtyOrder;$i++) {

                        $arrayOrder = array();
                        $productId = $item->getProductId();

                        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                        $taxClassId = $_product->getTaxClassId();
                        $taxClass = Mage::getModel('tax/class')->load($taxClassId);
                        $taxClassName = $taxClass->getClassName();
                        preg_match_all('/\-(.+)\%/', $taxClassName, $hsnRate);
                        $hsnRate = $hsnRate[1][0];
                        $hsnRate = $hsnRate / 100;
                        $hsn = $_product->getAttributeText('hsn');

                        array_push($taxName, $taxClass);


                        if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
                            $invIncrementIDs = array();
                            foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
                                $arrayOrder['invoice'] = $inv->getIncrementId();
                            }
                        }
                        /*echo '<pre>';*/
                        //var_dump($order);exit();
                        //$arrayOrder[]

                        $arrayOrder['hsn_rate'] = ' ';
                        $statusOrder = $order['status'];
                        $orderNo = $order['increment_id'];
                        $arrayOrder['shipping_amount'] = $order['shipping_amount'];
                        $arrayOrder['shipping_withouttax'] = number_format(($order['shipping_amount'] / 1.05), 2, '.', '');
                        $arrayOrder['shipping_rate'] = 0.05;
                        $arrayOrder['shipping_hsn'] = 996531;
                        $arrayOrder['status'] = $order['status'];
                        $arrayOrder['increment_id'] = $orderNo;
                        //$arrayOrder['created_at'] = substr($order['created_at'], 0, 10);
                        $arrayOrder['created_at'] = $order['created_at'];
                        $arrayOrder['customer'] = $order['customer_firstname'] . ' ' . $order['customer_lastname'];
                        $arrayOrder['tracking'] = $trackingNumber ? $trackingNumber : ' ';
                        $arrayOrder['titleTracking'] = $titleTracking ? $titleTracking : ' ';
                        $arrayOrder['state'] = $regionOrders ? $regionOrders : 'India';
                        $arrayOrder['tax_amount'] = $order['base_grand_total'];
                        $arrayOrder['hsn'] = $hsn ? $hsn : ' ';
                        $arrayOrder['hsn_rate'] = $hsnRate ? $hsnRate : ' ';

                        $arrayOrder['hsn_total'] = number_format((($item->getOriginalPrice() - $item->getDiscountAmount()) / (1 + $arrayOrder['hsn_rate'])), 2, '.', '');
                        $arrayOrder['price'] = $_product->getPrice();
                        $arrayOrder['special_price'] = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
                        $arrayOrder['percent'] = 100 - number_format(($_product->getSpecialPrice() /$_product->getPrice() * 100), 2, '.', '');
                        $arrayOrder['shipping_description'] = $order['shipping_description'];

                        $arrayOrder['item_count'] = $order['total_item_count'];
                        $arrayOrder['item_count1'] = number_format($order['total_qty_ordered'], 0, '.', '');


                        //$sumTax = $arrayOrder['hsn_total'] * $arrayOrder['hsn_rate'];
                        $sumTax = $item->getTaxAmount();

                        if ($arrayOrder['state'] == 'Maharashtra') {
                            switch ($arrayOrder['hsn_rate']) {
                                case 0.05:
                                    $arrayOrder['CGST-2.5%'] = $sumTax / 2;
                                    $arrayOrder['SGST-2.5%'] = $sumTax / 2;
                                    break;
                                case 0.03:
                                    $arrayOrder['CGST-1.5%'] = $sumTax / 2;
                                    $arrayOrder['SGST-1.5%'] = $sumTax / 2;
                                    break;
                                case 0.12:
                                    $arrayOrder['CGST-6%'] = $sumTax / 2;
                                    $arrayOrder['SGST-6%'] = $sumTax / 2;
                                    break;
                                case 0.18:
                                    $arrayOrder['CGST-9%'] = $sumTax / 2;
                                    $arrayOrder['SGST-9%'] = $sumTax / 2;
                                    break;
                                case 0.28:
                                    $arrayOrder['CGST-14%'] = $sumTax / 2;
                                    $arrayOrder['SGST-14%'] = $sumTax / 2;
                                    break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            switch ($arrayOrder['hsn_rate']) {
                                case 0.03:
                                    $arrayOrder['IGST-3%']  = $sumTax;
                                    break;
                                case 0.05:
                                    $arrayOrder['IGST-5%']  = $sumTax;
                                    break;
                                case 0.12:
                                    $arrayOrder['IGST-12%'] = $sumTax;
                                    break;
                                case 0.18:
                                    $arrayOrder['IGST-18%'] = $sumTax;
                                    break;
                                case 0.28:
                                    $arrayOrder['IGST-28%'] = $sumTax;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        $shippingSum = $arrayOrder['shipping_amount'] - $arrayOrder['shipping_withouttax'];
                        if ($arrayOrder['state'] == 'Maharashtra') {
                            switch ($arrayOrder['shipping_rate']) {
                                case 0.05:
                                    $arrayOrder['SCGST-2.5%']   = $shippingSum / 2;
                                    $arrayOrder['SSGST-2.5%']   = $shippingSum / 2;
                                    break;
                                case 0.03:
                                    $arrayOrder['SCGST-1.5%']   = $shippingSum / 2;
                                    $arrayOrder['SSGST-1.5%']   = $shippingSum / 2;
                                    break;
                                case 0.12:
                                    $arrayOrder['SCGST-6%']     = $shippingSum / 2;
                                    $arrayOrder['SSGST-6%']     = $shippingSum / 2;
                                    break;
                                case 0.18:
                                    $arrayOrder['SCGST-9%']     = $shippingSum / 2;
                                    $arrayOrder['SSGST-9%']     = $shippingSum / 2;
                                    break;
                                case 0.28:
                                    $arrayOrder['SCGST-14%']    = $shippingSum / 2;
                                    $arrayOrder['SSGST-14%']    = $shippingSum / 2;
                                    break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            switch ($arrayOrder['shipping_rate']) {
                                case 0.03:
                                    $arrayOrder['SIGST-3%']     = $shippingSum;
                                    break;
                                case 0.05:
                                    $arrayOrder['SIGST-5%']     = $shippingSum;
                                    break;
                                case 0.12:
                                    $arrayOrder['SIGST-12%']    = $shippingSum;
                                    break;
                                case 0.18:
                                    $arrayOrder['SIGST-18%']    = $shippingSum;
                                    break;
                                case 0.28:
                                    $arrayOrder['SIGST-28%']    = $shippingSum;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        if ($statusOrder == 'canceled') {
                            $arrayOrder['hsn']          = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['hsn_rate']     = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['hsn_total']    = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['CGST-0%']      = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['SGST-0%']      = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['CGST-1.5%']    = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['SGST-1.5%']    = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['CGST-2.5%']    = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['SGST-2.5%']    = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['CGST-6%']      = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['SGST-6%']      = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['CGST-9%']      = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['SGST-9%']      = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['CGST-14%']     = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['SGST-14%']     = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['IGST-3%']      = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['IGST-5%']      = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['IGST-12%']     = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['IGST-18%']     = 0;
                            $arrayOrder['IGST-28%']     = 0;
                        }
                        if($arrayOrder['hsn'] == 4014){
                            $arrayOrder['hsn_rate'] = 0;
                        }
                        array_push($arrayOrders, $arrayOrder);
                    } // for End
                }
            }

            //exit();
            $csv = '';
            $headerTax = array('Date', 'Order No','Invoice', 'Order Status', 'Customer Name', 'Tracking No', 'Curier Name', 'State','Order Amount Total', 'HSN', 'HSN GST Rate %', 'HSN Total in Invoice', 'CGST@0%', 'SGST@0%', 'CGST@1.5%', 'SGST@1.5%', 'CGST@2.5%', 'SGST@2.5%', 'CGST@6%', 'SGST@6%', 'CGST@9%', 'SGST@9%', 'CGST@14%', 'SGST@14%', 'IGST@3%', 'IGST@5%', 'IGST@12%', 'IGST@18%', 'IGST@28%');
            $csv .= implode(",", $headerTax) . "\n";
            $i = 0;

            foreach ($arrayOrders as $arrayTaxes) {

                $arrayTaxes['CGST-0%'] = $arrayTaxes['CGST-0%'] ? $arrayTaxes['CGST-0%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SGST-0%'] = $arrayTaxes['SGST-0%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SGST-0%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['CGST-1.5%'] = $arrayTaxes['CGST-1.5%'] ? $arrayTaxes['CGST-1.5%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SGST-1.5%'] = $arrayTaxes['SGST-1.5%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SGST-1.5%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['CGST-2.5%'] = $arrayTaxes['CGST-2.5%'] ? $arrayTaxes['CGST-2.5%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SGST-2.5%'] = $arrayTaxes['SGST-2.5%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SGST-2.5%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['CGST-6%'] = $arrayTaxes['CGST-6%'] ? $arrayTaxes['CGST-6%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SGST-6%'] = $arrayTaxes['SGST-6%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SGST-6%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['CGST-9%'] = $arrayTaxes['CGST-9%'] ? $arrayTaxes['CGST-9%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SGST-9%'] = $arrayTaxes['SGST-9%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SGST-9%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['CGST-14%'] = $arrayTaxes['CGST-14%'] ? $arrayTaxes['CGST-14%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SGST-14%'] = $arrayTaxes['SGST-14%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SGST-14%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['IGST-3%'] = $arrayTaxes['IGST-3%'] ? $arrayTaxes['IGST-3%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['IGST-5%'] = $arrayTaxes['IGST-5%'] ? $arrayTaxes['IGST-5%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['IGST-12%'] = $arrayTaxes['IGST-12%'] ? $arrayTaxes['IGST-12%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['IGST-18%'] = $arrayTaxes['IGST-18%'] ? $arrayTaxes['IGST-18%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['IGST-28%'] = $arrayTaxes['IGST-28%'] ? $arrayTaxes['IGST-28%'] : ' ';
                if(strpos($arrayTaxes['customer'],',')){
                    $arrayTaxes['customer'] = str_replace(',',' ',$arrayTaxes['customer']);
                }
                $arrayTaxes['SCGST-0%'] = $arrayTaxes['SCGST-0%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SCGST-0%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SSGST-0%'] = $arrayTaxes['SSGST-0%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SSGST-0%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SCGST-1.5%'] = $arrayTaxes['SCGST-1.5%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SCGST-1.5%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SSGST-1.5%'] = $arrayTaxes['SSGST-1.5%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SSGST-1.5%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SCGST-2.5%'] = $arrayTaxes['SCGST-2.5%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SCGST-2.5%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SSGST-2.5%'] = $arrayTaxes['SSGST-2.5%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SSGST-2.5%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SCGST-6%'] = $arrayTaxes['SCGST-6%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SCGST-6%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SSGST-6%'] = $arrayTaxes['SSGST-6%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SSGST-6%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SCGST-9%'] = $arrayTaxes['SCGST-9%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SCGST-9%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SSGST-9%'] = $arrayTaxes['SSGST-9%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SSGST-9%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SCGST-14%'] = $arrayTaxes['SCGST-14%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SCGST-14%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SSGST-14%'] = $arrayTaxes['SSGST-14%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SSGST-14%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SIGST-3%'] = $arrayTaxes['SIGST-3%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SIGST-3%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SIGST-5%'] = $arrayTaxes['SIGST-5%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SIGST-5%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SIGST-12%'] = $arrayTaxes['SIGST-12%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SIGST-12%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SIGST-18%'] = $arrayTaxes['SIGST-18%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SIGST-18%'] : ' ';
                $arrayTaxes['SIGST-28%'] = $arrayTaxes['SIGST-28%'] ? $arrayTaxes['SIGST-28%'] : ' ';
                if ($arrayTaxes['shipping_amount'] == 69.0000) {
                    $list = array($arrayTaxes['created_at'], $arrayTaxes['increment_id'],$arrayTaxes['invoice'], $arrayTaxes['status'], $arrayTaxes['customer'], $arrayTaxes['tracking'] , $arrayTaxes['titleTracking'], $arrayTaxes['state'], $arrayTaxes['tax_amount'], $arrayTaxes['hsn'], $arrayTaxes['hsn_rate'], $arrayTaxes['hsn_total'], $arrayTaxes['CGST-0%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-0%'], $arrayTaxes['CGST-1.5%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-1.5%'], $arrayTaxes['CGST-2.5%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-2.5%'],
                        $arrayTaxes['CGST-6%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-6%'], $arrayTaxes['CGST-9%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-9%'],
                        $arrayTaxes['CGST-14%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-14%'], $arrayTaxes['IGST-3%'], $arrayTaxes['IGST-5%'], $arrayTaxes['IGST-12%'], $arrayTaxes['IGST-18%'], $arrayTaxes['IGST-28%']);
                    $csv .= implode(",", $list) . "\n";
                    ++$i;
                    if ($arrayTaxes['item_count1'] == $i) {
                        $shipping = array($arrayTaxes['created_at'], $arrayTaxes['increment_id'],$arrayTaxes['invoice'], $arrayTaxes['status'], $arrayTaxes['customer'], $arrayTaxes['tracking'] , $arrayTaxes['titleTracking'], $arrayTaxes['state'], $arrayTaxes['tax_amount'], $arrayTaxes['shipping_hsn'], $arrayTaxes['shipping_rate'], $arrayTaxes['shipping_amount'], $arrayTaxes['SCGST-0%'], $arrayTaxes['SSGST-0%'], $arrayTaxes['SCGST-1.5%'], $arrayTaxes['SSGST-1.5%'], $arrayTaxes['SCGST-2.5%'], $arrayTaxes['SSGST-2.5%'],
                            $arrayTaxes['SCGST-6%'], $arrayTaxes['SSGST-6%'], $arrayTaxes['SCGST-9%'], $arrayTaxes['SSGST-9%'],
                            $arrayTaxes['SCGST-14%'], $arrayTaxes['SSGST-14%'], $arrayTaxes['SIGST-3%'], $arrayTaxes['SIGST-5%'], $arrayTaxes['SIGST-12%'], $arrayTaxes['SIGST-18%'], $arrayTaxes['SIGST-28%']);
                        $csv .= implode(",", $shipping) . "\n";
                        $i = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    $list = array($arrayTaxes['created_at'], $arrayTaxes['increment_id'],$arrayTaxes['invoice'], $arrayTaxes['status'], $arrayTaxes['customer'], $arrayTaxes['tracking'], $arrayTaxes['titleTracking'] , $arrayTaxes['state'], $arrayTaxes['tax_amount'], $arrayTaxes['hsn'], $arrayTaxes['hsn_rate'], $arrayTaxes['hsn_total'], $arrayTaxes['CGST-0%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-0%'], $arrayTaxes['CGST-1.5%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-1.5%'], $arrayTaxes['CGST-2.5%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-2.5%'],
                        $arrayTaxes['CGST-6%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-6%'], $arrayTaxes['CGST-9%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-9%'],
                        $arrayTaxes['CGST-14%'], $arrayTaxes['SGST-14%'], $arrayTaxes['IGST-3%'], $arrayTaxes['IGST-5%'], $arrayTaxes['IGST-12%'], $arrayTaxes['IGST-18%'], $arrayTaxes['IGST-28%']);
                    $csv .= implode(",", $list) . "\n";

                }

            }

            $fileName = 'SellerReport.csv';
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $csv);

            //Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Unable to find item to save'));
            //$this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong?

Comment: change **dsnews_admin** to **dsnewsadmin** and check

Comment: @QaisarSatti, same result after changing this.

Comment: controller path?

Comment: If you have just installed the module you should first try logging out and logging back in the admin area.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, this is controller path: DS/News/controllers/Adminhtml/NewsController.php

Comment: @Zankar, It is old module and working fine on demo site.

Comment: I have added my controller in question

Comment: @VinodKumar local version and demo version?

Comment: Live version... demo code is same

Comment: @QaisarSatti I understand. But if you have _just_ installed the module on _your_ site then you need to re-login for the admin page to appear.

Also double check if the module is enabled ;)

Comment: @Zankar thanks really appreciated your help.